# c# how to while loop textboxes so it changes textbox every loop?

Tags: c#, sql, loops, textbox, while-loop

I'm pretty new to c# and I'm struggling with this,

I'm trying to make a program that can send "items" to the names I type in the textboxes all at once with SQL stored produce.

I want to while loop textboxes so it changes from textBox1 to textBox2 and so on when it loops. I want to do this cause I have 45 texBoxes and a loop should be good I guess.

this is what I've tried:

```
int x = 1;
while (x < 46)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "EXECUTE usp_GiftItem @sendUser, @SendNickname, @receiver, @itemname, @text, @paymentType, @bOutput";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SendUser", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "123";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SendNickname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox89.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@receiver", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textbox(x).Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox80.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024).Value = textBox88.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@paymentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@bOutput", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1";
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Item sent", "Success");
    cn.Close();
    x++;
}
```

The problem is at @recivers value

I hope you there is a solution to this.
Thank you, Much appreciated

Comment: Any comments for the downvotes?

Comment: Although I don't have an issue with how you're using the `while` loop, a `for` loop would be a better choice.  You can create `x`, define the number of loops, and increment in one line.  `for (int x = 1, x < 46, x++) { ... `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, ... };
while(x ...)
{
    something[x] = textBoxes[x].Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it's working. :]
I wish I could vote up but my reputation is only 1 :s

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things if you do some preparation first. To example, you can create an array of items, where index of item is a `TextBox` number and item itself is an object what will be used to generate bold part: cmd.Parameters.Add( **"@blablabla", type, num** ).Value .

So:

```
 public class MyData
 {
     public string Text;
     public SqlDbType Type;
     public int Number;

     public MyData(string text, SqlDbType type, int number = 0)
     {
         Text = text;
         Type = type;
         Number = number;
     }
 }

 MyData[] data = new MyData[45] { new MyData("@bOutput", SqlDbType.VarChar), new MyData(...), ... };
 TextBox[] control = new TextBox[45] {textBox1, textBox2, ... };

 for(int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
     cmd.Parameters.Add(data[i].Text, data[i].Type, data[i].Number).Value = control[i].Text;
```

There are still things to improve, to example, instead of enumerating `TextBox`'es you may want to find them on the form (`form1.Controls`). Instead of generating data[] - it can be a part of `TextBox.Tag`, where you parse it and then generate parameters. Processing of the `Number` can be optional, etc..

But this should give you an idea.